# Find all packages in the project

Tags: java, reflection, package

I'm trying to know the packages I created in my project, and then goes deeply throw each package to know the classes.

Thus, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise what you want to do. Otherwise `find src_directory/ -name "*.java"` would list all your classes.

Comment: Quick answer is yes. You'll need to show what you've tried if there's something you need help with.

Comment: I'm trying to develop small java web app, I created single servlet to handle multiple request, and this servlet has multiple controllers(methods such as: add,delete,...), I need to access all classes that contain these methods

Answer (score 0):

The [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library should be helpfull for that, if you want to do it during runtime without trying to read the .jar file(s). Should allow you to list all classes from your base package (for example com.ibrahim or whatever you are using).

Comment: by using this library, should I provide the (Reflections) with package name?

Comment: If you want to use it to dynamically search clases on the classpath, then I suggest refering to the documentation since I couldn't do anything else than copy and paste it for your anyway ;-)